# How to hyperlink a file(pdf) stored in folder in Cpanel in Php

Tags: php, html, pdf, href

I am new to Php and have been facing a pretty small issue for which I cannot find info on Internet.

We have a PHP website hosted on Cpanel. 
there is a tab in the header which directs to a pdf file. I just want it to open in a new tab.

Below is the code : -

```
<div class="top-menu"><a href="<?php echo PUBLIC_BASE_URL . 'docs/' . $view_data['pds']; ?>" target="_blank">Documents</a></div>
```

Its not working. I've checked the value of "$view_data['pds'];" and thats not an issue. The file is located in Home/secure_html/docs/abc.pdf

however, the below header logo works perfectly fine. and it is located in 
Home/secure_html/assets/images/logo.jpg.

```
<div class="header-logo"><a href="<?php echo PUBLIC_BASE_URL; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $libURL->get_web_asset_url(); ?>images/logo.jpg" width="143" height="53" border="0" alt=""></a></div>
```

How can I quickly fix, or please provide me links to reference a PDF file in Php.
Any links to href and mapping the server path much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: is the Home folder within the public_html folder? Can you paste the rendered html from the php?

Comment: secure_html is publicly available...  it has Read/Execute permissions (User/Group/World).  and the page that  accesses the content is in Home/secure_html/vsc. I dont think the issue is of permissions because the doc folder and the images folder both have same permission World (Read/Execute) perhaps the images is well within the assets folder.

Comment: Can you paste the rendered html from the php?

Comment: for the PDF it is <a href="http://www.liniam.com/docs/abc.pdf" target="_blank">Documents</a>     and for the image its      <img width="143" height="53" alt="" src="https://secure.liniam.com/assets/images/logo.jpg" border="0">. 
 I couldnt find the method get_web_asset_url() its not in controller folder .... I dont have the manual either...